# How to get a function memory address from a Delegate

Tags: c#, assembly, delegates, hook, function-pointers

I'd like to hook a function from a DLL loaded in the same process, so each time that function is called my custom function is executed instead.

In order to do that, I have declared a dummy function that will be the one executed in replace of the original function from the DLL:

```
 public static bool hookFunc(string a, ulong b, string c, IntPtr d)
{
     Console.WriteLine("hi");
     return true;
}
```

After that, I declare a `Delegate` and I generate a new instance of it pointing to my **hookFunc** function and then I get a pointer from the delegate using `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()`. I also generate the bytes sequence that I will use to patch the original function's memory and I complete this sequence using the memory address of my function **hookFunc** (obtained from the new pointer):

```
public delegate bool hookDel(string a, ulong b, string c, IntPtr d);

public void hookManager()
        {

            var a = new hookDel(hookFunc);
            var hookPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(a);
            var hookPointerBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(hookPtr.ToInt64());
            newBytes = new byte[] { 0x49, 0xbb, hookPointerBytes[0], hookPointerBytes[1], hookPointerBytes[2], hookPointerBytes[3], hookPointerBytes[4], hookPointerBytes[5],
                                    hookPointerBytes[6], hookPointerBytes[7], 0x41, 0xff, 0xe3 };
        }
```

At this point, the content of the variable `newBytes` translated to assembly should be the following instructions:

```
mov r11, [memory address of my hookFunc function]
jmp r11
```

Finally, I get the original DLL's function memory address with GetProcAddress and I patch the first bytes with WriteProcessMemory, using for that replacement the content of the variable `newBytes`. After getting several StackOverflow errors, I have debugged the code with **WinDbg** and I discovered that the variable `hookPointerBytes` does not contain the address of **hookFunc**, therefore when the hook is triggered the `jmp` instruction is driving the code execution flow to a memory address where there is not executable code, and this is probably the reason why my program crashes.

I've verified that the DLL's function hooking is successfully completed and the `jmp` instruction is being executed. My question is, why am I not getting the real memory address of **hookFunc** by using the pointer obtained from the `Delegate`? Is there any other way in C# to get the memory address of my **hookFunc** function?

Comment: My guess is that your problem is that the delegate is being garbage collected.  According to the documentation for `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`: "You must manually keep the delegate from being collected by the garbage collector from managed code. The garbage collector does not track references to unmanaged code."

Comment: @RossRidge I've tried what you say using GC.KeepAlive() on the delegate and the pointer, and still getting the same error.

Comment: @KuroshD. You want `GCHandle.Alloc()` not `GC.KeepAlive()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are going to get this to work without unsafe code.
I think that you are going to require an unmanaged pointer which you can obtain via `ToPointer` on your `IntPtr`.

```cs
byte* pointer = (byte*) hookPtr.ToPointer();

for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
    newBytes[k+2] = *(pointer + k);
}
```

Ive not tried this myself but you can find an example of it done here: https://github.com/wledfor2/PlayHooky

Specific class:
https://github.com/wledfor2/PlayHooky/blob/master/HookManager.cs

Comment: I used a different approach but you were right, I needed unsafe code. Also, the PlayHooky code was the perfect guide to accomplish this task, so Ill vote your answer as correct.